# Check status of a company while login

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables companies & users i.e. company-id is defined as foreign key in users, while users of a specific company login to system first the company status should be checked if active, then its users can login otherwise should not be allowed. i tried a lot but couldn't and searched in google unfortunately couldn't find.
thank you in advance, if any one helps me.

```
Company.php => modal
      if (Auth::check()) {
        $id = Auth::user()->id;
        $companies = DB::table('companies')
        ->join('users', 'companies.company_id', '=', 'users.comp_id')
        ->select('companies.comp_status')
        ->where('users.id', $id)
        ->get();
        $compStatus = $companies[0]->comp_status;
        return $compStatus;
       }

        CompanyMiddleware.php => i defined
         public function handle($request, Closure $next)
         {
         if ( Auth::user()->compStatus() === 1) {
           return $next($request);
          }
         return redirect('login');

         }
```

Comment: I don't see you checking credentials/tokens anywhere.  Where are the credentials being checked here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$companies = DB::table('companies')
        ->join('users', 'companies.company_id', '=', 'users.comp_id')
        ->where('=','companies.comp_status', Companies::STATUS_ACTIVE)// i do not know how you define your company status so assuming you have constant
        ->where('users.id', $id)
        ->get();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: dear Leonenco, In fact i lost myself how to define its algorithm where i should check company status, status is define 0 for inactive and 1 for active but where can i check the status to allow users login or not allow if company is not active. for users status is easy but here as i already mentioned there are two tables and they are joint together.

Comment: Check company model, or company table, if company status 0 then it is disabled, otherwise learning is your way.